# Load class into val with Picasso

Tags: android, kotlin, picasso

I want to load a String out of a class to load it with picasso

```
val pic = String
    Picasso.get().load(User1::profileImageUrl).into(pic)
```

but the "load" gets a red line underneath it and it doesnt work.
here you can see my class

```
    class User1(val uid: String, val username: String, val profileImageUrl: String)
```

so later I want to use that string with glide like this

```
Glide.with(applicationContext).load(personPhotoUrl)
                    .thumbnail(0.3f)
                    .apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform())
                    .into(profilepicture!!)
```

any Ideas?

Comment: Picasso is an image loader library, just like Glide. What kind of "string" are you looking to obtain with it?

Comment: The load isn't underlined... `::` is, and should be just a `.`, and there is *no reason* to have both Picasso and Glide in the same app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with Picasso, but from javadoc load method takes String, Uri, File or resource id. You pass some kind of reflection reference on a property (if this construction makes sense at all).

If you want create pic one time you should use an instance of user:

```
val user : User1 = getUserSomewhere()
Picasso.get().load(user1.profileImageUrl).into(pic)
```

Or you can make a method:

```
fun loadUserProfileImage(user: User1, target: ImageView) {
    Picasso.get().load(user1.profileImageUrl).into(target)
}
```

Also underneath red line tells you that there is an error and it has a message of what's wrong.)

Also this: `val pic = String` is not correct, at least in your case. pic here is of type `StringCompanionObject`.